# Pythonic way of finding the overlapping elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, set

I have 2 regex which are extracting data and classifying them as feature-1 and feature-2 but in few scenarios the data gets classified as both feature-1(f1) and feature-2(f2).
ex : Amazon is 100 years old.

100 years old is classified as f1 and 100 years is classified as f2. and when its displayed on the UI. it gets displayed as 100 years old 100 years is wrong as only 100 years old needs to be displayed. In order to handle the superset and subset. I am trying to traverse through each feature and comparing if their is a overlapping feature f2. This code is working but its a huge performance hit if there are 25000 features to process.

```
`if df.iloc[i]['section_id'] == section_id and st_pos != -1:
    start_pos.append(st_pos)
    end_pos.append(en_pos)
    list.append(df.iloc[i]['id'])
'''
In the below loop, the positions are stored in  set form, If any subset found, then store it to list_subset
'''
        for i in range(0,len(start_pos)-1):
            for j in range(i+1,len(start_pos)):
                if 
    set(range(start_pos[i],end_pos[i])).issubset(range(start_pos[j],end_pos[j])):
    list_subset.append(list[i])
                elif 
    set(range(start_pos[j],end_pos[j])).issubset(range(start_pos[i],end_pos[i])):
    list_subset.append(list[j])`
```

Is their a better way to do this code pythonically?

Comment: If feature-1 matches, don't bother looking for feature-2.

Comment: f1 and f2 can be in single sentence. I will miss out the feature that I need to capture if they are in the same sentences.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say f1 starts at position 5 and is 4 letters long, so it occupies positions 5, 6, 7, and 8.  f2 will overlap if it starts in any of those positions, i.e. if f2's starting position is greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 8.

```
if f1_start_pos <= f2_start_pos <= f1_start_pos + f1_length - 1:
```

Presumably you would also need to check for the reverse condition:

```
if f2_start_pos <= f1_start_pos <= f2_start_pos + f2_length - 1:
```

Comment: I will try to implement this as my dataframe is slightly complicated. I will get back as soon as I have some breakthrough or questions. I will currently keep this query open and close it once I find a suitable resolution. Thanks John for helping out

Comment: I cannot mark your answer as my reputation is low :( Thanks again